# Can i retrieve 1-D array address from 2-D array?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I'm completely new to programming. This code is not working as I want, which is to retrieve 1-D array address from 2-D array:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
     int s[4][2] = {
                    { 1234, 56 },
                    { 1212, 33 },
                    { 1434, 80 },
                    { 1312, 78 }
                   };
     int i ;
     for ( i = 0 ; i <= 3 ; i++ )
         printf ( "\nAddress of %d th 1-D array = %u", i, s[i] ) ;
}
```

Comment: "*is not working*" is the more or less worth error description you can give. Please be more precise, what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: The code you submitted is fine, use `%p` instead of `%u` to print address in hexadecimal format.

Comment: use `(int*)s + i` instead of  `s[i]`, also `%p` instead of `%u`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `s[i]` itself an address pointing to each row, he is on right track

Comment: @jblixr OP want  retrieve 1-D array address.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I guessed OP wants to know the start address of each line, then `s[i]` is already the row address. Your code prints address of each value.

Comment: Ever heard of code formatting? It is not ok to just dump some random mess here and expect others to indent it for you.

Comment: @LPs Once you have your guess is correct, why OP thought it was _not working_?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY still guessing, because of OP wants to print the address and `%u` is not the right format.

Comment: @LPs I think if you think so and you should use `(void *)`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, you are formally right but gcc does not complain about that, even if `-Wall` is used. BTW I'm going to update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more precise and not using the C feature that an array is passed by a pointer to a function (`printf()` here), you can use a pointer to an array here:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
    int (*ptr)[2] = &(s[i]);

    printf ( "\nAddress of %d th 1-D array = %p\n", i, (void*)ptr) ;
}
```

The difference between `s[i]` and `&(s[i])` is, that `s[i]` **is** the 1d array, the type is `int[2]`, where `&(s[i])` is a pointer to `int[2]` , what you want here.

You can see it, for example,  with the `sizeof` operator: `sizeof(s[i])` is `2 * sizeof(int)` here, where `sizeof(&(s[i]))` has the size of a pointer variable.

Comment: `s[1]` and `&(s[i])` in fact are pointers to the same address, but being of different types.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    int s[4][2] = {
                    { 1234, 56 },
                    { 1212, 33 },
                    { 1434, 80 },
                    { 1312, 78 }
                } ;

    int i ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
        printf ( "\nAddress of %d th 1-D array = %p\n", i, (void *)s[i] ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in posted code use `%p` format to print addresses. This format specifier wants a `void *` as passed parameter.